# Mind boggling SQL dilemma

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Sorry for the title. I cannot come with anything meaningful for now but if you suggest anything I will update it.

OK, this problem has been bugging me for several days now and is driving me crazy.

I have a database that keeps education-related filters.

```
table: FILTERS

filterid filtertype value
1        school     MIT
1        school     UT
1        school     Lund
1        major      econ
1        major      civil
1        graduate   1
2        school     Harvard
```

So here I have two filters defined, 1 and 2. An education record passes filter1 if the school is one of (MIT,UT or Lund) AND major is one of (econ or civil) AND is a graduate program.
for passing filter2, an education record needs to just have Harvard as the school.

I have another table that holds education records for users. A user can have several education records (for example, one for her undergraduate studies, one for graduate)

```
table: EDUCATION
educid uid    school   major   graduate
1      1      MIT      econ    1
2      1      Lund     cs      0
```

So person 1 has two education records.
Here education record 1 passes filter 1, because the school (MIT) belongs to the set {MIT, UT, Lund), major (econ) belongs to the set {econ,civil} and is a graduate program. However, education record 1 does not pass filter 2 because the school is MIT, not Harvard.

Education record 2 does not pass filter 1 because major (cs) is not in {econ, civil}, and it does not pass filter 2 because the school is Lund, not harvard.

Person 1 does NOT pass filter 1, if none of her education records passes filter 1.
Therefore, person 1 passes filter 1 (because her first education record passes filter 1), but does not pass filter 2, because none of hiher s education records pass filter 2.

My goal is to SELECT the filterid of filters which person 1 does NOT pass.

This is what I have come to so far:

```
SELECT filterid FROM filters
LEFT JOIN education ON education.uid=1 AND (
(filtertype='school' AND filters.value=education.school) OR
(filtertype='major' AND filters.value=education.major) OR
(filtertype='graduate' AND filters.value=education.graduate) 
)
GROUP BY filterid
HAVING ( SUM(educid IS NULL)>0 )
```

This obviously does not work because according to this query person 1 does NOT pass filter 1 if one of her education records does not pass filter 1. (while it should be if none of her records passes filter 1).

I will really really appreciate any solution to this since it's really boggling my mind.

Comment: Your requirements are not 100% clear. Should person 1 pass filter 1 (since she has *at least one* of the required schools and at least one major and one graduate)? Or should she not pass, since she doesn't have *all* required schools in her education? Please add more examples.

Comment: Person 1 passes filter 1. As I explained: an education record passes filter1 if the school is ONE OF (MIT,UT, Lund) AND major is ONE OF (econ, civil), AND is a graduate program. for passing filter2, an education record needs to just have Harvard as the school.
So education record with educid=1 that belongs to person 1 passes filter 1. Therefore, person 1 passes filter 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot detect any information in your post whether person 1 passes filter 1. And please add at least one more example.

Comment: I added some more explanation. Hope it is more clear now. Let me know if it's not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it

```
SELECT f.filterid
  FROM filters f 
  LEFT JOIN education e1
    ON e1.uid = 1
   AND f.filtertype = 'school'
   AND f.value = e1.school
  LEFT JOIN education e2
    ON e2.uid = 1
   AND f.filtertype = 'major'
   AND f.value = e2.major
  LEFT JOIN education e3
    ON e3.uid = 1
   AND f.filtertype = 'graduate'
   AND f.value = e3.graduate
 GROUP BY f.filterid
HAVING MAX(e1.educid IS NOT NULL) +
       MAX(e2.educid IS NOT NULL) +
       MAX(e3.educid IS NOT NULL) < 3
```

or

```
SELECT f.filterid
  FROM filters f LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT uid, educid, 'school' type, school value
    FROM education
   WHERE uid = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT uid, educid, 'major' type, major value
    FROM education
   WHERE uid = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT uid, educid, 'graduate' type, graduate value
    FROM education
   WHERE uid = 1
) e 
    ON f.filtertype = e.type
   AND f.value = e.value
 GROUP BY f.filterid
HAVING MAX(f.filtertype = 'school' AND e.educid IS NOT NULL) +
       MAX(f.filtertype = 'major' AND e.educid IS NOT NULL) +
       MAX(f.filtertype = 'graduate' AND e.educid IS NOT NULL) < 3;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcd1d/24)** demo

Comment: Got it. Really awesome solution.

Comment: I found a problem with your answer. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f72cf/1/0
When I change the values for education table to:
 (1, 1, 'MIT', 'aero', 1),
 (1, 2, 'Lund', 'econ', 0)
Now user1 cannot pass filter1, because:
Her first education record does not pass filter1 since major aero is not in the set of acceptable majors.
Her second education record does not pass filter1 since it's not a graduate program.
Because none of her education records pass filter1, so user 1 should not pass filter1. But your query does not capture that.

Answer (score 1):

considering your tables as below

```
create table FILTERS(filterid int, filtertype varchar(100),value varchar(10))

insert into FILTERS values (1,'school','MIT')

insert into FILTERS values (1,'school','UT')

insert into FILTERS values (1,'school','Lund')

insert into FILTERS values (1,'major','econ')

insert into FILTERS values (1,'major','civil')

insert into FILTERS values (1,'graduate','1')

insert into FILTERS values (1,'school','Harvard')

create table EDUCATION (uid int, educid int, school varchar(100),major varchar(50),graduate varchar(10))

insert into education values (1,1,'MIT','econ','1')

insert into education values (1,2,'Lund','cs','0')
```

See these SQL's below - if they can be of any help...

```
select * from (
select a.uid, a.educid,a.filtertype,a.value,b.filterid, 
b.filtertype filtertype_1,b.value value_1 from (
select uid, educid,'school' filtertype,school value from education
union all
select uid, educid,'major' filtertype,major value from education
union all
select uid, educid,'graduate' filtertype,graduate value from education
)a right outer join filters b
on a.filtertype=b.filtertype and a.value=b.value
) c where c.uid is null

select * from (
select a.uid, a.educid,a.filtertype,a.value,
b.filterid from (
select uid, educid,'school' filtertype,school value 
from education
union all
select uid, educid,'major' filtertype,major value 
from education
union all
select uid, educid,'graduate' filtertype,graduate value 
from education
)a left outer join filters b
on a.filtertype=b.filtertype and a.value=b.value
) c where c.filterid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you'll get the idea, [fiddle example here (link)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11edf/1/0):

```
SELECT E.*, CASE WHEN (school.VALUE+major.VALUE+grad.VALUE) IS NOT NULL THEN 'PASS!'
    ELSE 'Fail: ' + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CASE WHEN school.VALUE IS NULL THEN 'school, ' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN major.VALUE IS NULL THEN 'major, ' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN grad.VALUE IS NULL THEN 'graduate, ' ELSE '' END), 3, 1000))
    END as Result
FROM EDUCATION E
LEFT JOIN FILTERS school ON school.FILTERID = 1 AND school.VALUE = E.school
LEFT JOIN FILTERS major ON major.FILTERID = 1 AND major.VALUE = E.major
LEFT JOIN FILTERS grad ON grad.FILTERID = 1 AND grad.VALUE = E.graduate
```

Or just get the educations that didn't pass, with reason for why, like so:

```
SELECT E.*, CASE WHEN (school.VALUE+major.VALUE+grad.VALUE) IS NOT NULL THEN 'PASS!'
    ELSE 'Fail: ' + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CASE WHEN school.VALUE IS NULL THEN 'school, ' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN major.VALUE IS NULL THEN 'major, ' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN grad.VALUE IS NULL THEN 'graduate, ' ELSE '' END), 3, 1000))
    END as Result
FROM EDUCATION E
LEFT JOIN FILTERS school ON school.FILTERID = 1 AND school.VALUE = E.school
LEFT JOIN FILTERS major ON major.FILTERID = 1 AND major.VALUE = E.major
LEFT JOIN FILTERS grad ON grad.FILTERID = 1 AND grad.VALUE = E.graduate
WHERE (school.VALUE+major.VALUE+grad.VALUE IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good idea, but can you also suggest a query with FILTERS being in the FROM syntax? The reason is that this is part of a bigger problem where I alsi have non-educational filters (like age, gender, etc). therefore I want to make the select from FILTERS table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table #FILTERS(filterid int ,filtertype varchar(20),value varchar(20))
insert into #FILTERS values(1,'school','MIT')
insert into #FILTERS values(1,'school','UT')
insert into #FILTERS values(1,'school','Lund')
insert into #FILTERS values(1,'major','econ')
insert into #FILTERS values(1,'major','civil')
insert into #FILTERS values(1,'graduate','1')
insert into #FILTERS values(1,'school','Harvard')


Create table #EDUCATION(uid int,educid  int,school varchar(20), major varchar(20),graduate int)
insert into #EDUCATION values(1,1,'MIT','econ',1)
insert into #EDUCATION values(1,2,'Lund','cs',0)
insert into #EDUCATION values(1,3,'Harvard','cs',0)

select * from #FILTERS 
select * from #EDUCATION

select * from #EDUCATION
where (Exists(select 1 from #FILTERS where #FILTERS.filtertype='School' and #FILTERS.value=#EDUCATION.school)
AND Exists(select 1 from #FILTERS where #FILTERS.filtertype='major' and #FILTERS.value=#EDUCATION.major)
AND Exists(select 1 from #FILTERS where #FILTERS.filtertype='graduate' and #FILTERS.value=#EDUCATION.graduate)
)
or
(#EDUCATION.school='Harvard')
```